# PHP Mail- Microsoft Outlook does not show attached content correctly

Tags: php, email, outlook

I m using following PHP code for email with `xyz.txt` file attached. All email clients except for Microsoft Outlook see the file content properly, but for outlook client, instead of actual file content the emailer body text gets printed in attached file i.e. "**Hi, Test file for 1st of October 2015** ".

I tried with different `boundary=\"PHP-alt-$uid\"` but no luck.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

File xyz.txt contain =>

> test10637|202.00|TEST|S|10637
>
> test10637|202.00|TEST|S|10637

```
    $myfile    = 'xyz.txt';
    $file_size = filesize($myfile);
    $handle    = fopen($myfile, "r");
    $content   = fread($handle, $file_size);
    $to        = "mahesh@gmail.com";

    fclose($handle);

    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    $message = "Hi, \nTest file for " . date("jS \of F Y",strtotime('yesterday')); // Hi, Test file for 1st of October 2015

    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

    $header = "From: TestMail <raj@gmail.com>\r\n";

    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $uid . "\"\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
    $header .= $message . "\r\n";
    $header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"Testfile.txt\"\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$myfile."\r\n";
    $header .= $content . "\r\n";


    $send =     mail($to, 'Test Subject', $message, $header);
```

Comment: the problem is only in outlook??

Comment: @SubinThomas : Thanks for comment. yes , problem is only for outlook.

Comment: I think better to use phpmailer etc @Raj

Answer (score 0):

Make the MIME message multipart/mixed and add two parts: one text/plain for the message body (it can be empty) and the actual attachment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please elaborate this answer

Comment: Outlook expects the body MIME part to be there. Include both the plain text body and the attachment.